# update data in access database using name two column

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, insert-update

update data in access database using name two column

because one column have same data because SerialNumber and Start can be Repeat

that's make update in all row have same data

i use this code but i have syntax Error

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {


            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "update Timer set Stop='" + label1.Text + "'where (SerialNumber,Start)='" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "' ";

            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");

            connection.Close();
            send_data f2 = new send_data(comboBox1.Text,label2.Text);
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERORR" + ex);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: In SQL a `WHERE` clause would compare the column values separately, e.g. `where SerialNumber = @Foo and Start = @Bar`. Probably not applicable to the software you have chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the WHERE clause is

```
 WHERE fieldname operator value AND/OR fieldname operator value ....
```

So the correct way to update that record is

```
string query = @"update Timer set Stop=? where SerialNumber = ? AND Start = ?";
command.CommandText = query;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", label1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", comboBox1.Text );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", textBox1.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice that before the WHERE keyword you need a space and I have changed your code to use a more secure parameterized approach instead of string concatenation